# How do I use VBA to paste distinct Excel rows on top of each other in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have an Excel 2013 spreadsheet (using Windows 10, 64-bit) with fifteen columns and variable rows with personnel data. My office is cutting-and-pasting rows in Excel as shapes in PowerPoint and organizing the data by division. This is being done manually.

My co-workers are manually going through hundreds of rows, without any VBA.

1. Copy data from the first row in Excel
2. Paste it into PowerPoint as a text box or shape
3. Resize the text box to fit in its own division or column
4. Change the text color and border properties for some text boxes
5. Move the text box to a desired location on the slide
6. Repeat for the next row until complete.

VBA should automate this process. The final PowerPoint must show an organization chart on a single slide. The text-boxes should appear very small (almost unreadable) on my computer screen. Perfect for a poster-sized print out. To test the VBA code, I placed random numbers in cells B2:O215. In Column A, I placed various Division names, such as "Div A", "Div B", ..., "Div E". The VBA should:

1. Loop through and copy each row of Excel data (starting with row 2)
2. Use a Switch...Case to identify the Division (e.g., Case "Div A")
3. With Case "Div A", paste the Excel row to PowerPoint on the slide
4. With Case "Div B", paste the Excel data to the right of "Div A"
5. Repeat with every division
6. Keep space between each Division's column.
7. The Width of each data-shape should be 2" (so 2*72 I think)
8. If a random number in Column D < 0.2, color text red

The code below stacks the Excel data on top of each other so that you can't see them. I want to be able to see each data row to look like a table. Each row must be distinct so leadership can move them around. Sometimes, the code will stop prematurely. Finally, I am not sure how to achieve step 8 above.

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

'Copy Range from Excel
  Sheets("Sheet1").Select

' Find the last row of data
  FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12) '12 = ppLayoutBlank

'Copy Excel Range

' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based not blank
    ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
    If Not IsEmpty(ThisValue) Then
        'Now the row is copied
        Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 15).Copy

            Select Case ThisValue
                Case "Div A"
                   'Paste to PowerPoint and position
                   mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
                   Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

                   'Change the shape of the text box
                   myShape.Left = 0.25 * 72
                   myShape.Top = myTop + 72
                   myShape.Width = 2 * 72

                Case "Div B"
                   'Paste to PowerPoint and position
                   mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
                   Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

                   'Change the shape of the text box
                   myShape.Left = 3 * 72
                   myShape.Top = myTop + 72
                   myShape.Width = 2 * 72

                Case "Div C"
                   'Paste to PowerPoint and position
                   mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
                   Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

                   'Change the shape of the text box
                   myShape.Left = 5 * 72
                   myShape.Top = myTop + 72
                   myShape.Width = 2 * 72

                Case "Div D"
                   'Paste to PowerPoint and position
                   mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
                   Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

                   'Change the shape of the text box
                   myShape.Left = 7 * 72
                   myShape.Top = myTop + 72
                   myShape.Width = 2 * 72

                Case "Div E"
                   'Paste to PowerPoint and position
                   mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
                   Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

                   'Change the shape of the text box
                   myShape.Left = 9 * 72
                   myShape.Top = myTop + 72
                   myShape.Width = 2 * 72

            End Select
    End If
Next x
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    PowerPointApp.Activate

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```